# .NET: don't get SQLite in-memory database to work

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Trying to understand the use of in-memory SQLite databases, I read about it in the SQLite documentation, and (I think) nearly everything I could find here in stackoverflow about it.

I want to copy a table from a local database into an in-memory database.

To understand how SQLite in-memory databases work I created this code:

```
Private Sub Test()
  Dim intTemp As Integer
  Dim strSQL As String

  Dim conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=':memory:';Version=3;New=True;")
  conn.Open()

  strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Table_1 (Table_1ID [VARCHAR(5)] NOT NULL, Item [VARCHAR(40)]);"
  Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(strSQL) With {
      .Connection = conn
    }

  strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table_1;"
  ' Test (1): Result: 0
  intTemp = cmd.ExecuteScalar

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (Table_1ID, Item) VALUES ('1000', 'Book');"
  cmd.CommandText = strSQL
  ' Test (2): Result: 1
  intTemp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

  strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table_1;"
  ' Test (3): Result: 0
  intTemp = cmd.ExecuteScalar
End Sub
```

Somehow it seems to work: when I insert a record into a table, the result is 1. But when I then count the records, the result is 0.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Is there anywhere a working sample, in C# or in VB.Net? Maybe even with a solution for my original problem: to copy a  table from a local database into an in-memory database? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `COUNT` sql you have forgotten to change the `CommandText`, so you again inserted a record.

```
strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table_1;"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL             ' this was missing   '
intTemp = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())  ' Now this returns 1 '
```

For this reason it is a good idea to use multiple commands for different queries.

Sidenote: you should use the `Using`-statement for objects using unmanaged resource. In case of a connection this will also close it before it is disposed, even in case of an error:

```
Using conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=':memory:';Version=3;New=True;")
    conn.Open()

    Using cmd = New SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE Table_1 (Table_1ID [VARCHAR(5)] NOT NULL, Item [VARCHAR(40)]);", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (Table_1ID, Item) VALUES ('1000', 'Book');"
        Dim inserted as Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table_1;"
        Dim count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using       
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how often I checked my code, but I didn't see it. Thanks also for the hint on using "Using"!

Comment: I was playing with this in C# and got an invalid cast using int. Tested with GetType and found out it was returning Int64.

Comment: @Mary you should really set Option strict on, as default

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have Option Strict on always.

Comment: @Mary no, then the last line im the method wouldn't compile because ExecuteScalar returns Object but you assign it to an integer variable. Compare with my code. I'm using CInt to cast it. edit, sorry, thought you were OP

Comment: @TimSchmelter `int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` compiles fine but gives me a runtime error - invalid cast. `Int64 count = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` works fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have used `CType` in vb.net which isn't the same as the cast operator of C#. If you wanted the same behavior use `DirectCast`. `CType` has builtin magic. `Convert.ToInt32` will be used to make the long a short.